# Error in gmax(<my_variable>) : object 'my_variable' not found

Tags: r, data.table

I'm running the following code, and I get the error mentioned in the title when I run it.

```
dt.placements[,.(first.received = min(file.dt)
                                ,last.received = max(file.dt)
                                ,SUB_ACCT_NO_SBB=max(SUB_ACCT_NO_SBB)
                                )
                              ,by=.(SUB_ACCT_NO_SBB,EQP_SERIAL_EQP)]
```

Can someone please explain to me why I am getting this message and how to fix my code. This code was working for me before I added the 3rd line--I added it to try to take out duplicates in the results.

Comment: Can you post a MWE with an example data set?

Comment: @Prevost What is an MWE?

Comment: It is a minimum working example. There are some recommendations at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. What I find is that in trying to reproduce my problem, often times I will see what is causing the error and then fix it (even though I already spent a lot of time formulating the question and preparing data!).